# Google sheet custom function return editing problem

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I am trying to make a custom function in google sheet that take two argument and fill the cell from where it was called and its adjacent cell also will be fill. Adjacent cell also need to accept other value. I use

```
function replaceAdjacent(a,b) {
    let c=[a,b];
    return [c];
}
```

This function fill both cell by provide argument but when i try edit the adjacent cell than it show  **#REFerror**.

How can I avoid this error with adjacent cell make editable?

Comment: Probably you can use the standard `textjoin()` function instead https://www.sheetaki.com/how-to-use-textjoin-function-in-google-sheets/ not sure if it will work with non-manually changing adjacent cell, though

Answer (score 2):

A cell value must be set manually or calculated by a formula, it cannot be both, that is why you get the **overwrite data error**.

You can call your function using a button and update the cell values using `setValues()`, this way you can set data manually or by calling your function.